# specify "fill value" in rbind.fill

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

ds2 already contains an NA. I want to distinguish between the "already there" NA and the NA that are generated by the fill.

```
library(plyr)
l <- LETTERS[]
ds1 <- data.frame(a=l[1:3],b=l[5:7],c=l[7:9],d=l[10:12],stringsAsFactors = F)
ds2 <- data.frame(a=NA,b=l[23], c=l[22],stringsAsFactors = F)

rbind.fill(ds1,ds2)
```

gives:

```
     a b c    d
1    A E G    J
2    B F H    K
3    C G I    L
4 <NA> W V <NA>
```

## i want that:

```
     a b c    d
1    A E G    J
2    B F H    K
3    C G I    L
4 <NA> W V  foobar
```

## i need a general solution to set a specific "fill value" when rbinding dataframes.

I know i could distinguish the NAs like that:

```
ds2[is.na(ds2)] <- "alreadyFooBar"
rbind.fill(ds1,ds2)

              a b c    d
1             A E G    J
2             B F H    K
3             C G I    L
4 alreadyFooBar W V <NA>
```

## Is there a possibility the other way around?

Comment: Please dont downvote without giving feedback! How can i improve then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should get you what you are looking for:

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
l <- LETTERS[]
ds1 <- data.frame(a=l[1:3],b=l[5:7],c=l[7:9],d=l[10:12],],stringsAsFactors = F)
ds2 <- data.frame(a=NA,b=l[23], c=l[22],stringsAsFactors = F)

NewCols <- setdiff(colnames(ds1),colnames(ds2))
ds2[NewCols] <- "fooBar"
rbind.fill(ds1,ds2)
```

Gives:

```
     a b c      d
1    A E G      J
2    B F H      K
3    C G I      L
4 <NA> W V fooBar
```

Comment: very nice. That way is works even with base rbind which i would suggest here.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I created that function i can rely on in the future. Even both inputs can have missing columns

```
fast.rbind <- function(x,y,value=NA){
    x[setdiff(colnames(y),colnames(x))] <- value

    y[setdiff(colnames(x),colnames(y))] <- value

    return(rbind(x,y))
}

x <- data.frame(a=l[1:3],b=l[5:7],c=l[7:9],d=l[10:12],stringsAsFactors = F)
y <- data.frame(a=NA, z=l[22],stringsAsFactors = F)
fast.rbind(x,y,"foobar")
```